# Overflow: auto + translateZ prevent page scrolling

Tags: css, google-chrome, mobile

Here's a screencast that demonstrates the following issue:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUGgtWAtsLQ

I'm building a web app aimed at mobile. I have a layout with several horizontal strips of images with `overflow: auto` that can be scrolled horizontally. So far so good - but when you scroll the page vertically there is noticeable [jank](http://jankfree.org/).

To fix that I apply `transform: translateZ(0);` to the strip row to force a composting layer, which indeed fixes the jank.

The major downside is that once I've done that, it is **no longer possible to vertically scroll the page when starting the scroll on one of the strips**.

How can I overcome this while remaining jank-free?

Relevant codepen:
http://codepen.io/OpherV/full/zGMrwo
(Run in chrome's device emulation mode, landscape orientation)

---

Edit: looks like the latest version of chrome on desktop fixed this bug, but it remains on mobile

Answer (score 0):

On iOS devices, you can smooth it using:

```
 translate3d(0,0,0).
```

It allows the browser to use iOS hardware acceleration.

Idea found at [Paul Irish's site](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/dom-html5-css3-performance/), and suggested by [Remy Sharp (video)](https://youtu.be/IKl78ZgJzm4) (yet not found at [Remy Sharp's website](https://remysharp.com/)):